# SQL: Insert Rows and interpolate

Tags: sql

I have a large SQL table and I want to add rows so all issue ages 40-75 are present and all the issue ages have a db_perk and accel_perk which is added via liner interpolation.

Here is a small portion of my data

```
class gender iss_age dur db_perk accel_perk ext_perk
111   F      40      1   0.1961  0.0025     0
111   F      45      1   0.2985  0.0033     0
111   F      50      1   0.472   0.0065     0
111   F      55      1   0.7075  0.01       0
111   F      60      1   1.0226  0.0238     0
111   F      65      1   1.5208  0.0551     0
111   F      70      1   2.3808  0.1296     0
111   F      75      1   4.0748  0.3242     0
```

I want my output to look something like this

```
class gender iss_age    dur db_perk accel_perk  ext_perk
111   F      40         1   0.1961  0.0025      0
111   F      41         1   0.21656 0.00266     0
111   F      42         1   0.23702 0.00282     0
111   F      43         1   0.25748 0.00298     0
111   F      44         1   0.27794 0.00314     0
111   F      45         1   0.2985  0.0033      0
```

I basically want to have all the columns, but iss_age, db_perk, and accel_perk be the same as the column above

Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  I would also suggest simplifying the data to only include the columns that are relevant to the question.

Comment: What's the database and version of it? This answer can be very dependent on the specific database.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff I simplified the data

Comment: @PaulR1999 what is the logic for `db_perk` & `accel_perk` for the additional rows added ? you had mentioned about - added via linear interpolation, can you elaborate this ?

Comment: @Mjoy basically just took 45's db_perk - 40's db_perk and then divided that by five. then just added that number to the one below